# Generating dynamic ERB using ERB generator

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, generator

For most of my projects, I use the same ole view for my index pages. The html is usually along the lines of this.

Desired html outcome:

```
<h1>Chairs</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Fabric</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @chairs.each do |chair| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= chair.color %></td>
        <td><%= chair.size %></td>
        <td><%= chair.fabric %></td>
        <td><%= chair.description %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

Fairly straight forward. The issue I'm having is that the generator I'm creating uses ERB tags to create the html code. I need to use ERB tags to create ERB tags.

```
<h1><%= plural_table_name %></h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <%- if !options[:fields].empty? -%>
      <%- options[:fields].each do |field| -%>
      <th><%= field.capitalize %></th>
      <%- end -%>
    <%- end -%>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
****  <%- @plural_table_name.each do | singular_table_name | -%>
      <%- if !options[:fields].empty? -%>
        <%- options[:fields].each do |field| -%>
          <tr>
****        <td><%= singular_table_name.field %></td>
          </tr>
        <%- end -%>
      <%- end -%>
 ****  <%- end  -%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i have, but it's obviously wrong. `options[:fields]` is an array that's working correctly because the `<thead>` block is showing what I need it to. My issue is creating an ERB tag that will return an ERB string rather than running the code that's inside. I believe I isolated the issue and noted the lines with `****`. I need these lines to show as is, but I need `plural_table_name` and `singular_table_name` to change dynamically according to the table. I'm not sure what the proper syntax is or if it's even possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it parsed twice? e.g. parse the erb and return erb and then parse again to generate html?

Comment: @engineersmnky Essentially, yes. I'm looking to run my generator to create my html file for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double percents, `<%%`, to escape `<%` in Erb (i.e. Erb will read `<%%` and write `<%` to the output, and won’t treat the contents as Ruby).

You will need to do things like:

```
<%% <%= a_plural_variable %>.each do | <%= a_singular_variable %> | %>
```

to get the output you want. This line will be evaluated to (assuming appropriate values for variables):

```
<% chairs.each do | chair | %>
```

Note the last `%>` is interpreted as plain text and doesn’t need escaping.